# NUnit results file in TeamCity

Tags: nunit, teamcity

With TeamCity 8, how do I produce / find a results file for an NUnit run?

We currently also run MsTest which produces a TRX file. We then use a TRX->HTML report tool to pass a report up the management food chain. How do we do the same with NUnit in TeamCity?

Right now I'm thinking I need to execute NUnit as a CommandLine build step, but that seems crazy considering there's an NUnit add-in and the MsTest add-in offers me a "Results file:" option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeamCity executes MSTest and NUnit differently.

NUnit is not run through the NUnit console executable but instead through TeamCity's own NUnit runner. This allows TeamCity to report NUnit test results on the fly--executing test 3...4...5...of 78--and allows instant notification of failed tests, even if all tests have not yet been executed.

MSTest, on the other hand, goes directly through the MSTest executables and does not have on-the-fly reporting. There is no progress other than "in progress". Test Results, including any failures, are only reported after every tests has been run.

TeamCity requires and parses the MSTest TRX file to do its own reporting, including on any failures, so it is also made available to you. However, the NUnit reporting files are a part of the NUnit console, and not a part of the TeamCity runner, so there is no report file to provide.

If you need the report file, you will need to run the NUnit tests through the NUnit console. There are [several ways](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/NUnit+Support) of doing this, only one of which is using a Command Line step. But be aware, you will lose the on-the-fly reporting, no matter which alternative you use.

Comment: Thanks Jay - unfortunately this is the root I took. Shame TeamCity's built in NUnit runner doesn't output an XML file :(

Answer (score 3):

Jay's description is correct; this is the TeamCity behaviour that makes this task impossible out of the box.

There is a known workaround though:

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5218450#5218450

Essentially, you invoke the TeamCity NUnit runner manually (e.g. from MSBuild). The runner can then output a result.xml file (one per test assembly). Those result files then have to be merged back into one in order to simulate the behaviour of `nunit-console`.

Davy Brion has even posted the MSBuild tasks for this:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080808215345/http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/07/using-teamcitys-nunit-support-while-keeping-the-output-around/

http://web.archive.org/web/20080809002009/http://davybrion.com/blog/stuff/

He has since nuked his blog, so waybackmachine to the rescue. In case those links die too, here are the snippets:

> #### NUnitMergeOutput
>
> This task combines the output of multiple NUnit xml reports into one combined xml  report.
> The combined report will contain the results of each xml report that was fed to it, and  it contains the total number of tests, failures, duration and overall success status of the entire test run.
>
> To define the task:
>
> ```
> <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Libs\Brion.MSBuildTasks\Brion.MSBuildTasks.dll"
>            TaskName="NUnitMergeOutput"/>
> ```
>
> And to use it in a target:
>
> ```
> <CreateItem Include="TestResults\*.xml" >
>   <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="NUnitOutputXmlFiles"/>
> </CreateItem>
>
> <NUnitMergeOutput NUnitOutputXmlFiles="@(NUnitOutputXmlFiles)"
>                   PathOfMergedXmlFile="TestResults\TestResults.xml" />
> ```
>
> #### BuildTeamCityNUnitArguments
>
> TeamCity doesn’t easily allow you to enable its integrated NUnit testing support while still keeping the NUnit output xml files around after the build. This task prepares an xml arguments file to pass to TeamCity’s NUnitLauncher task which does make it possible to keep the NUnit output xml in a directory you can specify. You can find more info on this problem here and more info on this workaround here.
>
> To define the task:
>
> ```
> <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Libs\Brion.MSBuildTasks\Brion.MSBuildTasks.dll"
>         TaskName="BuildTeamCityNUnitArguments"/>
> ```
>
> And to use it in a target:
>
> ```
> <CreateItem Include="**\Bin\Debug\*Tests*.dll" >
>   <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="TestAssemblies" />
> </CreateItem>
>
> <BuildTeamCityNUnitArguments HaltOnError="true" HaltOnFirstTestFailure="true"
>                             HaltOnFailureAtEnd="true" TestAssemblies="@(TestAssemblies)"
>                             NUnitResultsOutputFolder="TestResults"
>                             PathOfNUnitArgumentsXmlFile="nunitarguments.xml" />
>
>
> <Exec Command="$(teamcity_dotnet_nunitlauncher) @@ nunitarguments.xml" />
> ```

Comment: I wonder if there is a better way to do this now, since it's TC 8.0 and 2014 instead of 2008 when the above stuff was written?

Comment: The reason I needed to explore this was because I am seeing odd behaviour (suspected resource starvation) when executing `nunit-console` via command line build steps or powershell build steps. The TC nunit runner seems much better optimized.